# What to use instead of Application.DoEvents in my game?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm creating a Space Invaders game with C# WinForms and when coding the movement of the player's cannon, I create this event handler:

```
private void Game_Screen_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
    {

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
        {
            cannonBox.Location = new Point(cannonBox.Left - 2, cannonBox.Top); //Changes location of cannonBox to a new location to the left
            Application.DoEvents();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10); //Delays the movement by couple milliseconds to stop instant movement
        }

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
        {
            cannonBox.Location = new Point(cannonBox.Left + 2, cannonBox.Top); //Changes location of cannonBox to a new location to the right
            Application.DoEvents();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10); //Delays the movement by couple milliseconds to stop instant movement
        }

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
        {
            createLaser(); //Calls the method whenever Up arrow key is pressed
        }
    }
}
```

But going on different sites concerning how this is unreliable in C#, I am going to make sure to not use it from thereon. What other alternatives are there to use instead of Application.DoEvents within this instance?

Comment: A game loop is one of the few examples where using Application.DoEvents() is not fundamentally wrong.  But it belongs in the loop, not in an event handler.  Google "windows forms game loop" to find example code.

Comment: [Click](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/67651).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd suggest to make that event handler `async` and use `await Task.Delay()` instead of `Thread.Sleep()`:

```
private async void Game_Screen_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
        {
            cannonBox.Location = new Point(cannonBox.Left - 2, cannonBox.Top); //Changes location of cannonBox to a new location to the left
            await Task.Delay(10); //Delays the movement by couple milliseconds to stop instant movement
        }

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
        {
            cannonBox.Location = new Point(cannonBox.Left + 2, cannonBox.Top); //Changes location of cannonBox to a new location to the right
            await Task.Delay(10); //Delays the movement by couple milliseconds to stop instant movement
        }

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
        {
            createLaser(); //Calls the method whenever Up arrow key is pressed
        }
    }
}
```

This way, the control flow is returned to the caller and your UI thread has time to handle the other events (so no need for `Application.DoEvents()`). Then after (about) the 10ms, the control is returned and execution of that handler resumed.

There may more fine-tuning be necessary, because now of course you could manage to hit more keys while the method has not finished. How to handle that depends on the surroundings. You could declare a flag that signals current execution and refuses further method entries (no thread safety needed here as it's all happening sequentially on the UI thread).
Or instead of refusing re-entrance queue the keystrokes and handle them in another event, e.g. "idle" events (like Lasse suggested in the comments).

---

Note that an event handlers is one of the rare occasions where using `async` without returning a `Task` is ok.

Comment: thanks for the improvement! It's running far more smoothly than before and same without Application.DoEvents :)

Comment: Be aware that if you manage to press the left key (or it is being registered as pressed, autorepeat?) before that loop has finished you will essentially have two such loops running at the same time. 500 times 10 milliseconds is 5 seconds, that's more than enough time for something like this to happen.

Comment: You might instead simply record that the player wants to move to the left and move the actual movement code to some other event, like something like "Idle" or whatnot, then record that the player no longer wants to move to the left on key up.

Answer (score 2):

Use a **timer** that will call the game processing each 20 milliseconds.

Within the `KeyDown`/`KeyUp` events just change the current state which is used by the game processing.

Sample code:

```
[Flags]
public enum ActionState
{
    MoveLeft,
    MeveRight,
    FireLaser,
}

// stores the current state
private ActionState _actionState;

// set action state
private void Game_Screen_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    switch ( e.KeyCode )
    {
        case Keys.Left:
            _actionState |= ActionState.MoveLeft;
            break;
        case Keys.Right:
            _actionState |= ActionState.MoveRight;
            break;
        case Keys.Up:
            _actionState |= ActionState.FireLaser;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

// remove action state
private void Game_Screen_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    switch ( e.KeyCode )
    {
        case Keys.Left:
            _actionState &= ~ActionState.MoveLeft;
            break;
        case Keys.Right:
            _actionState &= ~ActionState.MoveRight;
            break;
        case Keys.Up:
            _actionState &= ~ActionState.FireLaser;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

// called from a timer every 20 milliseconds
private void Game_Screen_LoopTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ( _actionState.HasFlag( ActionState.MoveLeft ) && !_actionState.HasFlag( ActionState.MoveRight ) )
    {
        cannonBox.Location = new Point(cannonBox.Left - 2, cannonBox.Top); //Changes location of cannonBox to a new location to the left
    }
    if ( _actionState.HasFlag( ActionState.MoveRight ) && !_actionState.HasFlag( ActionState.MoveLeft ) )
    {
        cannonBox.Location = new Point(cannonBox.Left + 2, cannonBox.Top); //Changes location of cannonBox to a new location to the right
    }
    if ( _actionState.HasFlag( ActionState.FireLaser ) )
    {
        createLaser(); //Calls the method whenever Up arrow key is pressed
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Application.DoEvents() interupts the execution of your method and the UI thread will process its events (including redrawing of the UI). From my experience there is nothing wrong with using it in the right places...

Using the 'async' pattern (as René Vogt suggested) is best practice to make reponsive UI's.

However. You have to ask yourself if you need a loop that checks 500 times, if the key down is left, right or up. Especially as it seems this loop is triggerd by a key down event...

It would be maybe easier if you make a 'while(true)' loop in the main and call Application.DoEvents from there.

Or you react on the key_down event and do on action at a time. => press left -> move one left -> press left again -> move one left more... and so on.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: *"loop in the main"* - what is main? You mean [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/67681)?

Comment: more or less yes. The Main method is the entry point of a C# application.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/main-and-command-args/